# Magento 2: Data faker solution

Tags: magento2, data

I want to generate some fake data for testing on demand.  Either console script or button within admin.  Ideally have the option of generating x number of customers/customer addresses, orders (either as they are, invoiced or invoiced and shipped), products (simples are fine although could extend to other types), categories.  Essentially speed up extension and template development.

I always feel the sample data does more than it should.  I don't need all the other configuration changes.  Less/easier to delete after use.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?  Or know of an extension?

I looked at this https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-FakeMyData but I think this is the wrong approach

I was hoping to find an M2 version of this https://github.com/ovanschie/mageFaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Started to put together something myself. Enjoy!

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps, easy for your reference [generate more sample data](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html), we can use the below command to generate sample data profile (small, medium, large, and extra large).

```
bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/magento2/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for heads up.  [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html) for ref.  That's closer to what I need although would be better if you could pick and choose what to generate instead of choosing a profile.  I'm going to study the code to see if I can put together something myself.